# Get arrows on a line to point in the path of a flight

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology

I have created a 3D map of a drone's flight path. I would like the symbology for each data point along the path to be an arrow that points in the direction of the path. Here are the steps I have followed thus far:

Used the Points to Line tool both as shown below and with time selected for the Sort Field

[image]

Used the Split Line at Vertices tool with the input feature being the output of the Points to Line tool

Used symbology to place an arrow at the end of each line

Here is the outcome:

[image]

I'm not sure why the arrowheads are all oriented in the same direction. I'm also not sure why the lines are not visible coming off of each arrowhead given these are the symbology settings:

[image]

Comment: The out put map shown above is produced when arrow extended at end is chosen. When I choose one of the arrow line options, nothing shows up at all.

Comment: Don't split the line at the vertices, just apply symbology directly to your PointsToLine layer. Use a shape marker with placement 'On vertices', check boxes for 'Angle to line' and 'On regular vertices'.